# Angular router.redirect doesn't populate variables

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe checkout with my Angular 5 project and seem to be stuck on a router redirect / template lifecycle issue.

On user signup, I open the stripe checkout modal. When that modal get's a payment source token, I do some more API work and then do a router.redirect.

```
stripe.open({
  email: 'foo@foo.com',
  name: 'Subscription',
  description: 'Basic Plan',
  amount: 499,
  token: (source) => {
    this.http.post('/user/subscribe', { source: source.id }).subscribe(_ => {
      this.router.navigate(['stylist/profile']);
    });
  }
});
```

The app redirects properly, but the variables do not display whatsoever. Below is an example of my page. Ideally, the redirect would trigger the ngOnInit and the test variable would be true. In my scenario, the test is displayed in the html template as blank.

**Profile Route**

```
{ path: 'stylist/profile', component: ProfilePageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

**Auth Guard**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    public router: Router,
    public route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Profile Page Component**

```
export class ProfilePageComponent implements OnInit {
    test: boolean = false;

    ngOnInit() {
       this.test = true;
    }
}
```

**Profile Page HTML**

```
<div>Test variable: {{test}}</div>
```

This code has been simplified, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing any strange lifecycle events due to redirecting in a callback of a callback?

I've tried subscribing to various `Router` and `ActivatedRoute` events without any luck. I've also seen solutions involving `ngZone`, but those didn't seem to fit the bill either.

***01/07/19 UPDATE***

I was able to recreate this via stackblitz per the suggestion in the comments.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-un9tfk

Upon initial load of the homepage, you can click the "Open Stripe" button and fill out some dummy data. The callback then redirects to `/test` with a warning message in the console.

`Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?`

I believe this points me to doing `ngZone.run()`... somewhere in my `signup.component.ts`, but not sure where just yet.

Comment: Is stylist/profile the same page from where you trigger it? Or is it actually another route?

Comment: Showing the route declarations would help.

Comment: @IngoBürk The stripe snippet lives inside a signup component and is displayed on a home page currently. If I remove the stripe callback and just do a redirect, it seems to work.

Comment: Generally speaking this should work, so reproducing this in a Stackblitz would be helpful since I suspect that your question is so oversimplified (or incomplete) that the issue is hidden.

Comment: I'll try and recreate it in that. I haven't heard of that environment!

Comment: @IngoBürk I got around to recreating issue in stackblitz. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-un9tfk. You can use test credit card information 4111 1111 1111 1111 and exp 12/20, ccv 123. On initial page load of home, on callback, I get a warning complaining about ngZone so I think that may be part of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the edit above, it turns out using `Router.navigate` in a function callback is technically outside of an Angular zone.

Wrapping my `Router.navigate` in `NgZone.run(() => {})` did the trick.

Implemented solution:

```
import { Component, Input, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

signup() {
  stripe.open({
    email: 'foo@foo.com',
    name: 'Subscription',
    description: 'Basic Plan',
    amount: 499,
    token: (source) => {
      this.http.post('/user/subscribe', { source: source.id }).subscribe(_ => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['stylist/profile']);
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```